# Laravel: view->with passing an object

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, response

```
$somedata = Indicator::all();
$indicators = [];
// ... (re-structure the data; rows to columns)
$indicators[] = ['a'=>'2016', 'b'=>'2017', 'c'=>'2018'];
$indicators[] = ['a'=>'1232', 'b'=>'3242', 'c'=>'5467'];
$indicators[] = ['a'=>'1232', 'b'=>'3242', 'c'=>'5467'];
$indicators[] = ['a'=>'closed', 'b'=>'closed', 'c'=>'open'];> 

// ??? How to form a valid object to send ???
return view('indicators.index')->with(['indicators'=> $indicators]);
```

I select data. I change the structure for displaying it; but cannot find the correct structure to then pass in my response.

The view throws the error "Trying to get property of non-object (View: "

(I looked at the dump of Indicator::all(); and wonder if I have the right/wrong approach)

// noob

Comment: Please show the `indicators/index.blade.php` view

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an array, I image you are probably trying to access an index using object notation like:

```
$val->prop
```

when it should be:

```
$val['prop']
```

`Indicator::all()` returns a collection of objects which you're not using in your view.

As an aside, Laravel collections have some handy helper functions to work with result sets. You may be interested in:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map

Comment: That helps put me on the right track... PHP has changed since 1999!
So... I want to pass objects to remain consistent on the views. Is it necessary to create a little object class? Can I build it with some form of
        $rows[] = (object) [a->$month_0, b->$month_1, b->$month_1  ...  ];  What is the best practice ?

Comment: SOLVED:         $rows[] = (object) array('a'=>'3453', 'b'=>'5435', 'c'=>'345');

**Many thanks to everyone at StackOverFlow !**

Answer (score 0):

As `$indicators` is an array so you have to use `['']` instead of `->` to access its data.